# Excel: Reference table headers inside indices from cells

Tags: excel

Basic question: How can I reference a tables header from a cell?

Data contained under a headers can be referenced correctly like this:
=Table1[HeaderName]

I want to be able to write HeaderName inside a cell and reference that cell, like this:
=Table1[H2]

I suspect a simple solution & I've spent the last 2 hours googling so now I'm asking on here

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/emGq1.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use MATCH to locate the header, and INDEX to return the column

```
=INDEX(Table1[#Data],,MATCH(H2,Table1[#Headers],0))
```

Comment: Thanks. I ended up using `=INDIRECT("Table1"&"["&$H$2&"]")` instead but they both seem to do exactly the same thing

Comment: Indirect is undesirable when there is a viable alternative,  because it's Volitile, which can slow down your sheet